# How to do "git filter-branch --subdirectory <folderName>" with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have a lot of maven multi-module projects (around 50). Each of them with 1 to 4 sub-modules. Each multi-module project lies in a separate git repository. Due to an issue I need to split the modules into separate repositories.
I have a shell script to move a folder (a maven module) from Repo A to Repo B preserving its git history.

```
#!/bin/sh
# moves a folder from one git repository to another
# moveFolder <absolute repository one path> <repository one folder> <absolute repository two path>
echo "Moving "$2" from Repository: "$1" to Repository:"$3
# prepare repository one
cd $1
git clean -f -d -x
git checkout -b tmpBranch
git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter $2 HEAD
mkdir $2
mv * $2
git add .
git commit -a -m "CIRCLE-524: Moved "$2" into new repository"

#import in repository two
cd $3
git remote add repositoryOne $1
git pull repositoryOne tmpBranch
git remote rm repositoryOne

#cleanup
cd $1
git checkout master
git branch -D tmpBranch
```

When I have to do this for only a few projects i could do it manually. But because I have like 50 multi-module projects I like to automate this.

I could use a [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute this script. But the process of splitting all modules will be done on a windows machine.
(When I do this manually I'm using the Git Bash)


So I found [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) to automate my whole process with java. My problem is with `git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filder $2 HEAD`

 So far i have the following.

```
public static void revWalk(final Git repo) throws NoWorkTreeException, GitAPIException, MissingObjectException, IncorrectObjectTypeException, IOException {
        final Ref tmpBranch = checkOutBranch(repo, "tmpBranch");
        final Repository repository = repo.getRepository();
        try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
            final ObjectId commitId = repository.resolve(tmpBranch.getName());
            revWalk.markStart(revWalk.parseCommit(commitId));
            for (final RevCommit commit : revWalk) {

                System.out.println("Time: " + commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen() + " Message: " + commit.getShortMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

AND

```
public static void fileWalk(final Git repo, final String modulePath) throws IOException {
        final Ref head = repo.getRepository().findRef("HEAD");

        final RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo.getRepository());

        final RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
        final RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
        System.out.println("Having tree: " + tree);

        final TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repo.getRepository());
        treeWalk.addTree(tree);
        treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
        treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilterGroup.createFromStrings(modulePath));
        while (treeWalk.next()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + treeWalk.getPathString());
        }
        walk.close();
        treeWalk.close();
    }
```

`revWalk` checks out a new tmpBranch to work on and then lists ALL Commits with Time and Message.

`fileWalk` takes the HEAD and lists ALL files that match the given filter by the `modulePath`

I guess to achieve the `git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filder $2 HEAD` I have to combine both ways but to be honest I have no clue how to do that.
Could you please point me into the right direction and give me some code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I used the ProcessBuilder to execute my given script and I did the following.

```
private void executeScript(final String pathToGitBash, final File scriptFileToExecute, final String... arguments) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final int offset = 4;
        final String[] command = new String[arguments.length + offset];
        command[0] = pathToGitBash;
        command[1] = "--login";
        command[2] = "-i";
        command[3] = scriptFileToExecute.getAbsolutePath();
        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            command[i + offset] = arguments[i];
        }
        final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process process = builder.start();
        IOUtils.copy(process.getInputStream(), System.out);
        IOUtils.copy(process.getErrorStream(), System.err);
        switch (process.waitFor()) {
            case 1:
                LOGGER.error("Parameters for scripts are not correct.");
            break;
            case 0:
                LOGGER.info("Script seemed to execute properly");
            break;
            default:
                LOGGER.info("Unknown returnCode. Script finished with: {}", process.exitValue());
        }
    }
```

To execute it withing Gitbash I needed to provide the gitbash/sh.exe and the parameters "--login -i"